# Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[f(n)-\int_n^{n+1}\!f(x)\,\text{d}x\right]$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f$ be a non-negative decreasing function on $[1,+\infty)$. Prove that the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[f(n)-\int_n^{n+1}\!f(x)\,\text{d}x\right]$$
converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MathWorld, this is called [MacLaurin-Cauchy Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Maclaurin-CauchyTheorem.html).
A proof can be found, for example, in Burkill's book [A First Course in Mathematical Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=4gXNIY0B75YC&pg=PA141).
It is related to (generalized) [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Generalizations). See also the proof in Wikipedia article on [Integral test for convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). The picture from this article (which I copied below) can help your intuition, when you try to prove this result.

[image: Image copied from Wikipedia]

To find more useful stuff you search for *[MacLaurin Cauchy theorem](http://www.google.com/search?q=MacLaurin+Cauchy+theorem)* or *[MacLaurin Cauchy test](http://www.google.com/search?q=MacLaurin+Cauchy+test)*,
now that you know the name of the result.

Answer (score 9):

**HINT:**

Note that
$$f(n+1) \leq \int_n^{n+1} f(x)dx \leq f(n)$$