# Explain this inequality, related to logarithms

Tags: inequality, logarithms, approximation, integral-inequality

I am trying to understand a proof of Stirling's formula.

One part of the proof states that, 'Since the log function is increasing on the interval  $(0,\infty)$, we get 
$$\int_{n-1}^{n} \log(x) dx < \log(n) < \int_{n}^{n+1} \log(x) dx$$ for $n\geq 1$.'

Please could you explain why this is true?
In particular, I am struggling to visualise this inequality graphically/geometrically.

Comment: Have a look at the pictures posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156326/showing-inequality-for-harmonic-series/156330#156330), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857473/convergence-nth-harmonic-number-minus-the-natural-logarithm-of-n/857485#857485) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/680521) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/437959/). (Other similar posts can be found on this site.)
It is about function $f(x)=\frac1x$ rather than $f(x)=\log x$, but I guess you get the idea how this generalizes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\int_{n-1}^n\log(x) dx<\int_{n-1}^{n}\log( n) dx=\log(n)$$
using $\log(n)>\log(x)$ for  $n-1\leq x<n$.
Similarly:
$$\int_n^{n+1}\log(x)dx>\int_n^{n+1}\log(n)dx=\log(n)$$

Answer (score 2):

This because on $[n-1,n]$, we have $\,\ln x<\ln n\,$ except at the end point so that by the monotonicity property of the integral:
$$\int_{n-1}^n \ln x,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mux<\ln n\,[n-(n-1)]=\ln n.$$
Similarly for the other inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a strictly increasing continuous function in the interval $[a,b]$ (with $a<b$. Then, for $x\in[a,b]$, we have $f(x)\le f(b)$. Therefore
$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx\le (b-a)f(b)
$$
because $f(b)$ is the maximum of $f$ in the interval. Equality would mean
$$
\int_{a}^{b}(f(b)-f(x))\,dx=0
$$
and, as $g(x)=f(b)-f(x)$ is a continuous non negative function, this implies $f(x)=f(b)$ for all $x$, so the function is constant. This is impossible if $f$ is strictly increasing. Thus
$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx< (b-a)f(b)
$$

Similarly,
$$
(b-a)f(a)<\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx
$$

In your case there's only to verify that
$$
\int_0^1\log x\,dx<\log 1=0
$$
because $\log$ is not defined at $0$, so this is an improper integral. You should be able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The $\log$ function (whatever base of the logarithm you meant) is strictly increasing; its average value over any proper interval of numbers${}\leq n$ is less than $\log(n)$, and its average value over any proper interval of numbers${}\geq n$ is greater than$~\log(n)$. For intervals of length$~1$, the average is the integral.

Comment: If the base of a logarithm is less than 1, the logarithm is a decreasing function.

Comment: @user143462 I don't think anybody uses a bare $\log$ to stand for a logarithm to some (implicit) base between $0$ and $1$. But you are right.

Comment: It was a pedantic comment.  I teach plenty of Calculus courses, and so I find myself plotting plenty of exponential functions - to bases bigger than 1 and to bases less than 1 - and I find myself plotting their inverses.  I didn't want any confusion in case my students were reading this post.  (That is a totally sarcastic comment.)